# What happens if I edit a duplicate Hosts file?

Tags: filesystem, root, hosts

What exactly is a duplicate file?

When I wanted to edit the hosts file (`/private/etc/hosts`), it says:

> You don't own the file "hosts" and don’t have permission to write to
>   it.
>
> You can duplicate this document and edit the duplicate. Only the duplicate will include your changes.

So, if I do my edits in the duplicate `hosts` file, is it equivalent to having my hosts file edited?

Comment: I've changed the title of this question to "What happens if I edit a duplicate Hosts file?" which might bring future Googlers to it more easily. Please feel free to edit further, or revert my change if you are not happy with it.

Comment: @Tetsujin Looks appropriate. Thank you for making the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a poorly chosen vocabulary since in a MacOS X file system a **duplicate** is a serious error meaning that the file-system is deeply corrupted.

The correct term which should have been used here is the term of **copy**.

If you don't have permission to edit `/private/etc/hosts` then make a local **copy** as follows:

```
cp /private/etc/hosts ~/hosts
```

If you really need to edit the `/private/etc/hosts`, I advise you to make first a backup local **copy** as above. And once you have edited and thoroughly verified it,
put it back into place with `sudo` to get the admin priviledges:

```
/usr/bin/sudo cp ~/hosts /private/etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

The Hosts file is not owned by any user, it is owned by System (root). The standard way to edit it is to drag a copy to the desktop, edit that, then drag it back & authenticate. Then you need to change the owner back to root.

To avoid all this fiddling around, you could use [GasMask](http://clockwise.ee) (freeware), which allows you to edit, copy [duplicate] & keep multiple hosts files, instantly switchable.